# Moses' briefing before sending spies - Land vs People

Tags: eretz-yisrael, moshe-rabbeinu, parashat-shelach, meraglim-spies

Here's how the Torah depict Moses' briefing to the spies (Numbers 13) - first the whole passage:

> וּרְאִיתֶם אֶת־הָאָרֶץ מַה־הִוא וְאֶת־הָעָם הַיֹּשֵׁב עָלֶיהָ הֶחָזָק הוּא הֲרָפֶה הַמְעַט הוּא אִם־רָב׃ וּמָה הָאָרֶץ אֲשֶׁר־הוּא יֹשֵׁב בָּהּ הֲטוֹבָה הִוא אִם־רָעָה וּמָה הֶעָרִים אֲשֶׁר־הוּא יוֹשֵׁב בָּהֵנָּה הַבְּמַחֲנִים אִם בְּמִבְצָרִים׃  וּמָה הָאָרֶץ הַשְּׁמֵנָה הִוא אִם־רָזָה הֲיֵשׁ־בָּהּ עֵץ אִם־אַיִן וְהִתְחַזַּקְתֶּם וּלְקַחְתֶּם מִפְּרִי הָאָרֶץ וְהַיָּמִים יְמֵי בִּכּוּרֵי עֲנָבִים׃
>
> And see what kind of country it is. Are the people who dwell in it strong or weak, few or many? Is the country in which they dwell good or bad? Are the towns they live in open or fortified?  Is the soil rich or poor? Is it wooded or not? ...

Let's break this passage into the two objectives - the Land and the People:

> Land: וּרְאִיתֶם אֶת־הָאָרֶץ מַה־הִוא
> People: וְאֶת־הָעָם הַיֹּשֵׁב עָלֶיהָ הֶחָזָק הוּא הֲרָפֶה הַמְעַט הוּא אִם־רָב׃
> Land: וּמָה הָאָרֶץ אֲשֶׁר־הוּא יֹשֵׁב בָּהּ הֲטוֹבָה הִוא אִם־רָעָה
> People: וּמָה הֶעָרִים אֲשֶׁר־הוּא יוֹשֵׁב בָּהֵנָּה הַבְּמַחֲנִים אִם בְּמִבְצָרִים׃
> Land: ...וּמָה הָאָרֶץ הַשְּׁמֵנָה הִוא אִם־רָזָה הֲיֵשׁ־בָּהּ עֵץ אִם־אַיִן

As we see it goes back and forth alternatively, instead of listing all the question about the Land together and about the people together. Possible problems with this way:

- People don't talk this way (esp. Moses, are there other examples of such a pattern?)
- Torah uses extra words ומה הארץ

Why is that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiastic_structure

Comment: @DoubleAA Wait, it's not that, not even close. Here Moses talks, not how the author composed the story. Also it's  ABABA not ABBA.